# timer function for xpages xp:messages and hidden input

Tags: xpages

I am using a hidden input to store a message for displaying a computed value in a hidden input. I add a message string to the hidden input on postSaveDocument to show the document was saved sucessfully. Being new to this coming from classic Notes development I would like to know how to only have this show for a predetermined amount of time, like 5 seconds, and then go away. So how would I change the value of the hidden input to "" after the time lapse from postSave. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. One would be to run this CSJS when there is a message in your input field:

```
setTimeout('dojo.byId("#{id:divMessage}").innerHTML = ""', 5000);
```

I didn't quite get which element is showing your message (because you are talking about hidden input) but I assumed it's a `div` or `span`.

To set input field value you would use:

```
dojo.byId("#{id:inpMyInput}").value = ""
```

Comment: There is also setInterval() and clearInterval(). Be warned, that you should only set the timer lower then the keep alive timeout in the application properties.